# empty Maven mojo parameter instead of null

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, mojo

I was wondering whether it's possible to distinguish "parameter not specified" from "parameter is empty".  In both cases the Mojo parameter has the value null.

I want the default value to kick in, if the user does not give the parameter, and the empty string, if user gives the empty parameter element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a null in case of a string you can assume the user didn't defined it at all otherwise you can assume it had been defined. You can set appropriate default-values for Mojo parameters to distinguish between those cases. Or can you be more specific.

Comment: It looks like when you use `defaultValue = ""` in the `@Parameter` annotation Maven ignores it and does not set the parameter's value at all.